# How to redirect only main domain, without subdomain or files in folders?

Tags: .htaccess

I need redirect only domain, eg. `www.example.com`, but any subdomain cannot be redirected. Also, if I have files on `www.example.com/folder/file.pdf`, then those files should be available under the main domain. How to do it with a 301 redirect?

For eg.

```
www.example.com => redirect
www.sub.example.com => not redirected
www.example.com/folder/file.pdf => not redirected
```

Comment: What URL are you wanting to redirect to? The same URL-path, but on a different domain?

Comment: The point is I want redirect only main domain. Nothing else - no subdomains or paths under main domain. Main domain will be redirected to Facebook page.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to exclude specific folders from the domain that is being redirected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using mod_rewrite at the top of your `.htaccess` file. To specifcally match the domain name, you need a condition that checks against the `Host` HTTP request header.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^path/to/source\.html$ https://example.com/path/to/target.html [R,L]
```

If you are redirecting to the same domain, then you don't strictly need to specify a scheme+hostname in the *substitution* - but without knowing your server config, it is more reliable to do so.

To redirect all URL-paths to a different domain, but with the same URL-path, except the specific file you mentioned:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/file\.pdf$
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.net/$1 [R,L]
```

**UPDATE:**

> The point is I want redirect only main domain. Nothing else - no subdomains or paths under main domain. Main domain will be redirected to Facebook page.

If you simply want to redirect the document root of the main domain, eg. `example.com/` then you don't need to make any exceptions for folders/files you don't want to redirect, as you are only redirecting a single URL.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.facebook.com/page [R,L]
```

Comment: Ok, but if I have files in folder under my main domain then those are still redirected :/

Comment: My update only redirects `example.com/` (ie. the main domain) - it does not redirect any other URLs, including those in `folder`. Are you wanting to redirect all other URLs (eg. `/foo`, `/bar` etc.) but exclude just the `/folder` subdirectory?

Comment: I use this: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(prices/) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.mikrolove.pl [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.facebook.com/mikrolovepl [NE,L,R=301] and it's solved my problem :)

Comment: The `RewriteCond` directive to exclude `/prices` is superfluous, since the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (ie. `^$`) only matches the document root anyway.